# How to handle concurrency scenario on SQL Server with import functionality?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, concurrency

I have implemented import functionality on my web application, using this I will insert user details records into a `User` table. But when we open import form (view) in two different tabs of the browser and then upload the same Excel sheet with the same records in two forms at a time and finally click the submit button for inserting those records into the table, then two processes run at the same time and insert some records as duplicated.

So, how to handle that concurrency scenario?

Comment: What command/script are you using to insert records? And what is the logic you want to happen when a duplicate record found? How do you identify that two records are the same?

Comment: This isn't about concurrency, it's about data integrity. What stops the same user uploading twice one after the other? Your records need a unique identifier of some sort and use that to determine if the record should be inserted or updated.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
 When I applied Unique identifier on column name like 'LevelName' then stop add duplicate record but issue is in my system I have delete user as soft delete , not hard delete, so in that case unique key arise problem in import if second time insert same user with same level name then made problem